# Copy Content of Folder to other Folder in android

Tags: android, nio

How to copy all contents of Directory (not including Parent) to another directory in android.When I use below code I copyed source parent and contents,I wantto copy only contents. I got Files/Tmp/Contens, I want to copy like this Files/Contents

```
        File src = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "Tmp");
        File dir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "Files");

        try {
            Utils.copyFileOrDirectory(src.getAbsolutePath(),dir.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Copy File

```
public static void copyFileOrDirectory(String srcDir, String dstDir) {

    try {
        File src = new File(srcDir);
        File dst = new File(dstDir, src.getName());

        if (src.isDirectory()) {

            String files[] = src.list();
            int filesLength = files.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                String src1 = (new File(src, files[i]).getPath());
                String dst1 = dst.getPath();
                copyFileOrDirectory(src1, dst1);

            }
        } else {
            copyFile(src, dst);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
        destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    } finally {
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//try this...
  String sourcePath = 
  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
   + "/folder_name1";
        File source = new File(sourcePath);

        String destinationPath = 
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/folder_name2";
        File destination = new File(destinationPath);
        try 
        {
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FileUtils library

```
        File src = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "Tmp");
        File dir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "Files");

        try {
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(src,dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```